# Robocopy not copying proper last accessed time stamps

Tags: robocopy

I am using Robocopy 5.1.10 and it does not copy the last accessed time attribute on files. I am using below handlers with robocopy which copies all the data very well except the last accessed time stamp. Any idea if this is a issue with the version of robocopy im running on or am i missing anything in the handlers

robocopy   /E /ZB /COPYALL /R /W /V /LOG:

Answer (score 0):

the "last accessed timestamp" does not bear any weight in the determination of a change/update to decide on copy in consequent robocopy (/MIR etc) runs etc, but if that's of an application/usecase value to preseve, disable updating it before running the command then run the command:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959914.aspx